# VB Account retrieval program outputting two error messages

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an account retrieval program for computing coursework at school, which checks an inputted email address and password against that stored in a CSV file, if the input in correct then the program displays their user information, and if the input is incorrect it outputs an error message telling them so. I have created the program in Visual Basic and it works fine, except for when I press submit without entering anything into the input fields. When nothing is entered, the program calls the error message for no input, and the error message for an invalid/incorrect input. How do i fix this? My code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Password.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EmailAddress.Click

End Sub



Private Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Dim currentRow As String()
    Dim foundmatch As Boolean

    Using parserDetails As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("CSV_File.csv")
        parserDetails.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not parserDetails.EndOfData
            currentRow = parserDetails.ReadFields()

            If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailAddress.Text)) Then
                If EmailAddress.Text = currentRow(0) And Password.Text = currentRow(1) Then
                    Me.InfoDisplay.Rows.Add(currentRow)
                    foundmatch = True
                    Exit While
                End If
            Else 'null/empty or white space
                MsgBox("You need to type something into the input boxes")
                foundmatch = False
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End Using

    If Not foundmatch Then
        MsgBox("The email and/or password entered cannot be found or is incorrect.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Invalid Email")
    End If
End Sub




Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Input(p1 As String)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub

Private Sub Reset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Reset.Click
    EmailAddress.Text = Nothing
    Password.Text = Nothing
    InfoDisplay.Rows.Clear()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type in nothing, then you will end up in the else case in you while loop (null/empty or white space) for the first row in your csv, hence the message box "You need to type something into the input boxes" will be shown and additionally foundmatch will be False, which will cause "The email and/or password entered cannot be found or is incorrect." to be shown.

To fix this, I would suggest to move the whitespace checking out of the While loop and skip all the other operations if the input is empty.

Comment: Where would I move the whitespace?